# Ionic 2 missing ionic.css file

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm creating a new Ionic app that I need to take a lot of styling from an old app for.  The new app is ionic 2, the old is ionic 1.  The ionic 1 app is pulling a lot of styles from lib/ionic/css/ionic.css.  I can't find a similar thing in the ionic 2 app.  Where do I find this?  Do I just need to copy the file over?  And will there be collision issues with ionic 2?

Answer (score 0):

The css files would be under theme folder, app.core.scss where you define the folder path.

For example,

```
-App
--Pages
---Login(folder inside pages)
----Login.html
----Login.js
----Login.scss
---MainPage(folder inside pages)
--Theme
---app.core.scss(inside theme folder)
```

and define the folder path in app.core.scss :

```
@import "../pages/Login/Login";
```

Do note that the css styles are separated in ionic 2, but for my ionic 2 version, there are instances where same html ID css get mixed up, thus it would be better to have different IDs for different pages.

Comment: All those files are there.  I'm talking about a css file in www/lib/ionic that is being heavily utilized.  Looks like a library that comes from ionic.  I'm wondering if there is a similar thing in ionic 2.  Basically I'm trying to pull all that old ionic styling so I don't have to style it all myself.  But it's a massive file and I don't want to have some kind of collision situation between ionic 1 and ionic 2.

Comment: Have you found anything out? I'm wondering the same thing right now

Answer (score 0):

What boilerplate template did you use to create you app? There might be different structure for the folders and files. But the idea is that there will be bunch of .scss files in different folders which should be compiled to one css file when you build/serve the app.

For example there could be structure as indicated by @Gene or the main scss files could be in /app/app.scss and /theme/variables.scss, and  individual components scss will be in the component directories